# C Reading from txt file and Storing in Linked List

Tags: c, linked-list

My aim is to read from a text file line by line, and then divide each line into different variables. I tried to use fgets and successfully stored it into the linked list. But it stores the whole line, instead, I just want it to store it until semicolon. For example, the first line is:

```
1;IMG_3249.JPG;730x1114;158KB;Hamburg;Germany;16/03/2020 09:12
```

Here I want '1' to be stored in id, "IMG_3249" store in the name. It goes like this. So far I managed this;

```
struct list {
    char *string;
    int id;
    char *name;
    char *dim;
    char *size;
    char *location;
    char *date;
    struct list *next;
};
typedef struct list LIST;


int main ()
{
     FILE *fp;
     char line[110];
     LIST *current, *head;

     head = current = NULL;
     fp = fopen("PhotoInfoBook.txt", "r");

     while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)){
        LIST *node = malloc(sizeof(LIST));
        node->string = strdup(line);
        node->next =NULL;

        if(head == NULL){
            current = head = node;
        } else {
            current = current->next = node;
    }
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Any ideas about how I should proceed?

Comment: Take a look to `strchr` in `string.h`

Comment: Yes, replace `strdup(line)` with your own function which finds the first semicolon in the given line, allocates a string of the appropriate length, and copies all the characters up to the semicolon from the input line into the output string.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the call to `strdup(line)` with a call to your own function, which shall find the first semicolon in the given line, allocate a string of the appropriate length, and copy all the characters up to the first semicolon from the input line into the output string.

For example:

```
char* my_strdup(const char* line)
{
    int len;
    for (len = 0; line[len] != ';' && line[len] != 0; len++) { }
    char* new_line = malloc(len + 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
         new_line[i] = line[i];
    new_line[len] = 0;
    return new_line;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not specially fond of `strtok` because if modify the passed string and is not thread safe, but this is a correct use case for it. In fact it replaces delimiters (here the semicolons `;`) with null and allow to have pointers inside the passed string. This is a nice think here because `strdup` allocated the whole string. You could do:

```
 while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)){
    LIST *node = malloc(sizeof(LIST));
    node->string = strdup(line);
    node->name = strtok(node->string, ';');
    // if (node->name == NULL) error processing
    node->id = atoi(node->string);     // ok the firt ; is now a null
    node->dim = strtok(NULL, ';');
    ...
    node->date = (strtok(NULL, ';');
    node->next =NULL;
```

Error processing omitted for brievety...

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of functions that make this kind of processing easier and safer in C.  Read the man pages for getline, regexec, and strndup.  One other suggestion is to use the convention that the last item in your linked list is a sentinel that marks the end of the list.  It simplifies managing the list.

```
#include <regex.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct list_t {
  char *string;
  int   id;
  char *name;
  char *dim;
  char *size;
  char *location;
  char *date;
  struct list_t *next;
} list_t;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  FILE   *fp       = fopen("PhotoInfoBook.txt", "r");
  char   *line     = NULL;
  size_t  capacity = 0;
  list_t *head     = calloc(1, sizeof(list_t));
  list_t *iter     = head;
  regex_t re;
  regcomp(&re, "([0-9]+);([^;]+);([^;]+);([^;]+);([^;]+);([^;]+)", REG_EXTENDED);
  regmatch_t capture[7];

  while (getline(&line, &capacity, fp) > 0) {
    if (regexec(&re, line, 7, capture, 0) == 0) {
      iter->string   = strdup(line);
      iter->id       = strtoul(line, NULL, 10);
      iter->name     = strndup(&line[capture[2].rm_so], capture[2].rm_eo - capture[2].rm_so + 1);
      iter->dim      = strndup(&line[capture[3].rm_so], capture[3].rm_eo - capture[3].rm_so + 1);
      iter->size     = strndup(&line[capture[4].rm_so], capture[4].rm_eo - capture[4].rm_so + 1);
      iter->location = strndup(&line[capture[5].rm_so], capture[5].rm_eo - capture[5].rm_so + 1);
      iter->date     = strndup(&line[capture[6].rm_so], capture[6].rm_eo - capture[6].rm_so + 1);
      iter->next     = calloc(1, sizeof(list_t));
      iter           = iter->next;
    }
  }

  for (iter = head; iter->next != NULL; iter = iter->next) {
    printf( "line      : %s", iter->string);
    printf( "        id: %d\n", iter->id);
    printf( "      name: %s\n", iter->name);
    printf( "       dim: %s\n", iter->dim);
    printf( "      size: %s\n", iter->size);
    printf( "  location: %s\n", iter->location);
    printf( "      date: %s\n", iter->date);
  }

  return 0;
}
```